# How to match and replace undefined numbers of a pattern using re.sub

Tags: python, python-re

I wish to match a pattern in some text which occurs 0-n times and replace the text when this happens.

Here is some sample text

```
XYZ

WWW

OOO

|NOTE:

ABC

DEF

GHI

3+|

HERE
```

I want to convert the above text to the following (I only wish to convert the part between "|NOTE:" and "3+|"):

```
XYZ

WWW

OOO

|NOTE:ABCDEFGHI

3+|

HERE
```

Where the text above is contained in "input_txt", I can do it with the following code:

```
input_txt = re.sub(
    r'\|(NOTE):\n*(.*)\n*(.*)\n*(.*)(\n*[0-9]*[\+]*[\|]*)',
    r'|\1:\2\3\4\5',
    input_txt
    )
```

However, this code only works if there are three \n separated paragraphs after the "|NOTE:" text.
How do I change the so that it will match and replace any number of \n characters ? I would prefer to do this with re.sub if possible (for my own interest, as this is an issue I have come across before without knowing how to do it), but would also be open to other suggestions of how it might better be done.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
input_txt = re.sub(r'\n+([^0-9|])', r'\1', input_txt)
```

Output:

```
|NOTE:ABCDEFGHI
3+|
```

Comment: Can you please print the output you generated?

Comment: I think you only need the first line of code and one `re.sub()`.

Comment: I'm sorry.I typed an extra letter in my test text :(

Comment: Hi, I have added some additional details to the above, I did not express myself well the first time, sorry.